# Why is it not printing? NASM x86 Coding

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, histogram, nasm

This is what it is supposed to print

Enter a string written in some language: "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"

a:2 b:0 c:10 d:6 e:0 f:1 g:0 h:6 i:1 j:0 k:4 l:2 m:1 n:0 o:11 p:0 q:0 r:0 s:0 t:0 u:7 v:0 w:6 x:0 y:0 z:0
ocuwhdklamifzyxvtsrqpnjgeb

However mine just prints:
Enter a string written in some language: "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"

a:2 b:0 c:10 d:6 e:0 f:1 g:0 h:6 i:1 j:0 k:4 l:2 m:1 n:0 o:11 p:0 q:0 r:0 s:0 t:0 u:7 v:0 w:6 x:0 y:0 z:0

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

section .data
    msg     db      "Enter a string written in some language: ", 0

section .bss
    counters resd    26 ; an array of 26 counters, each storing a 4-byte value
    sorted   resd    26 ; an array of 26 letters, sorted by decreasing number of occurrences
    input    resd   1   ; to store the input character

section .text
    global asm_main

asm_main:
    ; setup
    enter   0, 0
    pusha

    ; print prompt
    mov eax, msg
    call print_string

    ; loop to count characters
    mov ebx, counters
loop:
    call read_char ; read input character
    cmp  eax, 10 ; check if end of input (newline character)
    je end ; if newline character, exit loop
    cmp eax, 97 ; check if lowercase
    jl upper_case ; if less than 97, ignore
    cmp eax, 122 ; check if lowercase
    jg not_alpha ; if greater than 122, check uppercase
    sub eax, 97 ; ASCII value subtract by 97 to get index
    jmp update_counter

lowercase_counter:
    cmp eax, 0
    je next
    add ebx, 4
    dec eax
    jmp lowercase_counter

upper_case:
    cmp eax, 65 ; check if uppercase
    jl not_alpha ;if less than 65, ignore it
    cmp eax, 90 ; check if uppercase
    jg not_alpha ; if greater than 90, ignore it
    sub eax, 65 ; ASCII value subtract by 65 to get index
    jmp update_counter

uppercase_counter:
    cmp eax, 0
    je next
    add ebx, 4
    dec eax
    jmp uppercase_counter

not_alpha:
    ; ignore non-letter characters
    jmp loop

update_counter:
    inc dword [ebx+eax*4]
    mov ebx, counters
    jmp loop

next:
    mov ebx, counters
    jmp loop

end:
    ; print character counts
    mov ebx, counters
    mov ecx, 97
loop2:
    cmp ecx, 122
    jg end2
    mov eax, ecx
    call print_char
    mov eax, 58
    call print_char ; print the colon character
    mov eax, [ebx]
    call print_int
    mov eax, 32
    call print_char
    inc ecx
    add ebx, 4
    jmp loop2

 ; sort letters by decreasing count
    mov eax, sorted
    mov ebx, counters
    mov ecx, 26

outer_loop:
    mov edx, [ebx]
    mov [eax], edx
    add eax, 4
    add ebx, 4
    loop outer_loop

    mov eax, sorted
    mov ebx, 24

sort_loop:
    mov ecx, 0

inner_loop:
    mov edx, [eax]      ; move the value of the first element of the array into edx
    mov ebx, [eax + 4]  ; move the value ofthe second element of the array into ebx
    cmp edx, ebx ; compare the two values
    jge skip_swap ; if the first value is greater than or equal to the second value, skip the swap
    mov [eax], ebx ; move the second value to the first element of the array
    mov [eax + 4], edx ; move the first value to the second element of the array

skip_swap:
    add eax, 4 ; move to the next pair of elements in the array
    loop inner_loop ; repeat until all pairs have been compared and swapped (if necessary)
    dec ebx             ; move to the next element in the array, excluding the last element since it is already sorted
    cmp ebx, 0          ; check if we have reached the beginning of the array
    jge sort_loop       ; if not, repeat the sorting process for the remaining unsorted elements

   ; print sorted letters and their counts
    call print_nl
    mov eax, sorted
    mov ebx, counters
    mov ecx, 26

print_sorted:
    cmp ecx, 0
    jle end2
    mov edx, [eax]
    add eax, 4
    sub ecx, 1
    cmp edx, 0
    je print_sorted   ; skip printing if the count is 0
    add edx, 97
    mov eax, edx
    call print_char
    mov ebx, 58      ; store the ASCII code for ":" in ebx
    call print_char  ; print ":"
    mov eax, [ebx + (edx - 97) * 4] ; retrieve the count using the letter's ASCII value
    call print_int
    call print_nl
    jmp print_sorted

    

end2:
    call print_nl
    popa ; clean up
    mov eax, 0 ; clean up
    leave ; clean up
    ret ; clean up
```

Comment: It looks like because you didn't implement anything (or deleted after implementing, maybe) to print the missing part `ocuwhdklamifzyxvtsrqpnjgeb`.

Comment: This [mcve] isn't very minimal, e.g. nothing ever jumps to the `lowercase_counter:` block, and the code in it doesn't make sense anyway.  Isn't it just doing `ebx += 4*eax` or something, which you could do with an addressing mode (e.g. as an LEA).  After wasting a couple minutes looking at that and then figuring out it was unreachable, I'm not interested in looking at more uncommented code which might or might not be doing anything.  Single-step with a debugger to see how your code executes.

Comment: Comments in `print_sorted:` talk about printing `:`, which is weird because you print the histogram in alphabetical order, not in frequency order.  So you'd only want to sort by frequency *after* that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not printing?

Your program does not output "ocuwhdklamifzyxvtsrqpnjgeb" because you already jump to the end right after having printed the counters.

> ```
>     ; print character counts
>     mov ebx, counters
>     mov ecx, 97
> loop2:
>     cmp ecx, 122
>     jg end2
> ```

Now the above error is kind of a blessing because if the sorting code were allowed to execute it would prove to contain an infinite loop. You initialized ECX=0 and then used the LOOP instruction. This code was going to loop 4 billion times!
Also, you are intending to use the EBX register for two totally different purposes: once as a counter of some kind and once as an array element. This is the exact stuff that crashes are made of. Why don't you use more different registers? You still have ESI, EDI, and EBP to play with.

---

You were attempting to descendingly bubble-sort a copy of the array with the counters. **Without precautions you will loose any connection to the letters from the alphabet**!
Personally, I would have included the characters somewhere in the records I was going to sort, but only use the actual count for determining the order:

```
  ; sort letters by decreasing count
  mov  edi, sorted
  mov  esi, counters
  mov  ecx, 00006100h     ; CH='a'
copy_loop:
  mov  eax, [esi]         ; Counter [0,255]
  add  esi, 4
  or   eax, ecx           ; Combine character in AH with count in AL 
  mov  [edi], eax
  add  edi, 4
  add  ecx, 00000100h
  cmp  ecx, 00007A00h     ; CH='z'
  jbe  copy_loop

  mov  ecx, 25            ; ECX is outer loop counter
outer_loop:
  mov  esi, sorted
  mov  edx, ecx           ; EDX is inner loop counter
inner_loop:
  mov  eax, [esi]
  mov  ebx, [esi + 4]
  cmp  al, bl             ; Compare the two COUNTS ONLY
  jge  skip_swap
  mov  [esi], ebx         ; But swap the WHOLE RECORD
  mov  [esi + 4], eax
skip_swap:
  add  esi, 4
  dec  edx
  jnz  inner_loop
  dec  ecx
  jnz  outer_loop
```

Now the memory at *sorted* looks like:

```
11, 'o', 0, 0, 10, 'c', 0, 0, 7, 'u', 0, 0, ...
```

And so you need to write *a simple loop* that retrieves the second byte from every dword, and just have it printed.

Don't use the current version of *print_sorted*. It contains many errors!